# How to make it so a PHP page is directed to the same page but with different variables

Tags: php, url, methods, get, calendar

Well I have a Calendar and would like to add links to the bottom that have the different months with a `-1` month and a `+1` month on either ends. I know I need to use the $_GET method in order to have a specific URL. However, I'm not sure what I need to do in order to have the page know what to do when it has that specific url.

Right now it is only a `../index.php` URL. And if I try to make the extension like `index.php?day=02&month=01&year=2014` it just displays the default page. So how do you make it so that if a user was to hardcode a different month or year in the URL, it would direct them to the correct calendar month.

Comment: Wheres your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<?php
$day = htmlspecialchars($_GET['day']);
$month = htmlspecialchars($_GET['month']);
$year = htmlspecialchars($_GET['year']);

if ($year == 2014) {
echo $day . $month . $year . " - This is the special Year Page! (would be a good idea to do an include here maybe?";
}

?>
```

That should give you some ideas as to how you can achieve what you are trying to do.